# How can I enable identity provider for cognito user pool via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using `terraform` to deploy cognito user pool but I can't find how I can enable identity provider, the `Cognito User Pool` checkbox in below screenshot.

I checked this doc https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_client but can't find an option to enable that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is option [supported_identity_providers](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_client#supported_identity_providers) with [possible values](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/create-user-pool-client.html) of:

> A list of provider names for the identity providers that are supported on this client. The following are supported: COGNITO , Facebook , Google and LoginWithAmazon